# Using ArrayList<SubClass> as method argument where parameter type is ArrayList<SuperClass>

Tags: function, inheritance, parameters, casting, arraylist

So I have two classes. Class `B` extends class `A`. I'm creating an `ArrayList` containing objects of type `B`, so the list is of type `ArrayList<B>`. I want to use that `ArrayList` in a method `useList` that has an input parameter type of `ArrayList<A>`. It stands to reason that since `B` is a child class of `A`, it can be used everywhere that `A` is, including in this application.

HOWEVER, the compiler doesn't seem to like this (see error messages in code below). I also tried casting my `ArrayList<B>` to `ArrayList<A>` when passing it into the method, but that one didn't work either.

Code:

```
public class Test {
    private class A { }
    private class B extends A { }
    public static void useList(ArrayList<A> aList) { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

        /* "The method test(ArrayList<Test.A>) in the type Test
         * is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Test.B>)" */
        useList(bList); 

        /* "Cannot cast from ArrayList<Test.B> to ArrayList<Test.A>" */
        useList((ArrayList<A>)bList);
    }
}
```

I'm undoubtedly doing something silly, so any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just declare `useList` to expect a parameter of type `ArrayList` with elements that extend `A`:

```
public static void useList(ArrayList<? extends A> aList) { }
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know you could do that! Java never ceases to surprise me. Works perfectly, thanks!